# Ошибка на Ubuntu: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Utils::chooseHandler()

Tags: php, wordpress, guzzle

Я пишу свой небольшой плагин на WordPress. Версия WP одна и та же, версия PHP тоже, использую последнюю версию MailChimp PHP API, но у меня на локальном севере (OpenServer на Винде) всё ок, но когда закидываю на GoDaddy или NameCheap, где серваки на Ubuntu, то получаю ошибку

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Utils::chooseHandler() in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/bullhorn-connect/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php:61 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/backwpup/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(42): GuzzleHttp\choose_handler() #1 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/backwpup/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(65): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create() #2 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/bullhorn-connect/vendor/mailchimp/marketing/lib/Api/AccountExportApi.php(54): GuzzleHttp\Client->__construct(Array) #3 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/bullhorn-connect/vendor/mailchimp/marketing/lib/Configuration.php(69): MailchimpMarketing\Api\AccountExportApi->__construct(Object(MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient)) #4 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/bullhorn-connect/admin/mailchimp-sync.php(38): MailchimpMarketing\Configuration->__construct() #5 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/bullhorn-connect/admin/mailchimp-sync-page.php(10): MyMailChimp->__construct() #6 /var/www/wp-content/plugi in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/bullhorn-connect/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php on line 61
```

Все файлы на месте, перед публикацией вызвал `composer dump-autoload` , переустановку composer делал, переустановку MailChimp API тоже делал.

Очень прошу помочь. Я уже не знаю, что делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема была в другом плагине. Автолоад композера другого плагина перекрывал мой автолоад. Обнаружил я это, выведя ReflectionMethod и увидев, что файл класса тянется с другой директории